# FileWriter vs FileOutputStream in Java

Tags: java

I'm little confused about `FileWriter` and `FileOutputStream`. As I see [source code of FileWriter](http://ktutorials.com/source/OpenJDK/java/io/FileWriter.java) there are just 4 constructors and each constructor is calling `FileOutputStream`'s constructor.

```
public FileWriter(String fileName) throws IOException {
       super(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
}
public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(fileName, append));
}
public FileWriter(File file) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(file));
}
public FileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(file, append));
}
public FileWriter(FileDescriptor fd) {
        super(new FileOutputStream(fd));
}
```

After searching difference between them I found [mentioned here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/fileoutputstream-vs-filewriter/).

> FileOutputStream is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as
>   image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using
>   FileWriter.

How `FileWriter` can make difference? Even it still calling `FileOutputStream`'s constructor without any changing.

Comment: The difference is in the `write()` method.

Comment: @Tunaki where is the read method in FileWriter? and Quote that I mentioned is saying about writing streams not read. can you explain please?

Comment: Erf I meant the write method, was confused...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`FileWriter` is a [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html). It's about writing *text* - and it happens to be writing it to a file. It does that by holding a reference to a `FileOutputStream`, which is created in the `FileWriter` constructor and passed to the superclass constructor.

`FileOutputStream` is an [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). It's about writing binary data. If you want to write text to it, you need something to convert that text to binary data - and that's exactly what `FileWriter` does. Personally I prefer to use `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` *by me* to allow me to specify the character encoding (as `FileWriter` always uses the platform default encoding, annoyingly).

Basically, think of `FileWriter` is a simple way of letting you write:

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter("test.txt");
```

instead of

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"));
```

Except I'd normally recommend using the overload of the `OutputStreamWriter` constructor that accepts a `Charset`.

Comment: But I'm confused there are just 4 constructors where is the difference? and each constructor is calling FileOutputStream's constructor.

Comment: @LetDoit: No, there aren't "just four constructors" - there are plenty of other methods as well, inherited from `OutputStreamWriter`. Yes, each constructor calls a `FileOutputStream` constructor, because every `FileWriter` has a reference to a `FileOutputStream`. But that doesn't mean `FileWriter` and `FileOutputStream` are the same thing.

Comment: is the difference in JVM? Because I was expecting coding difference too.

Comment: @LetDoit: No, the difference is that *they're entirely different classes*. The `FileWriter` constructor *creates* a `FileOutputStream` to pass to the superclass constructor (`OutputStreamWriter`) but after that, you use a `FileWriter` like any other `Writer`, writing text - and then `OutputStreamWriter` converts that text into binary data to pass to the `OutputStream` that it's wrapping.

Comment: I'm still confusing because in `FileWriter` there is no coding except constructors. `FileWriter` using `OutputStreamWriter` methods then why not direct `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"));` instead of  `new FileWriter("test.txt"); `That's why I'm confusing. I got all your points. But what's about coding?

Comment: @LetDoit: I don't know what you mean by "what's about coding". And yes, you can certainly ignore `FileWriter` is you want and just call the `OutputStreamWriter` constructor directly, passing in a `FileOutputStream` you've constructed. I do that often, in order to pass in a `Charset`. (These days I tend to use `Files.newBufferedWriter`, but that's a different matter.) But I'm still not sure what you're confused about. Do you understand that `FileWriter` inherits all the methods from `OutputStreamWriter`?

Comment: I understood about inherits that's why I'm confusing. Why `FileWriter` another class instead `OutputStreamWriter` without adding new methods or something else.

Comment: @LetDoit: Again, just for convenience. Because the first snippet of code in my answer is shorter than the second snippet.

Comment: I'm back to ask that I paste á character in filed that's ASCII is 225 in my OS and byte max_value is 127. and I used `FileInputStream` to just `read()` then why it returning 225? how it is able to read more than one byte? because `read()` method just read one byte or character at a time.

Comment: @LetDoit: There's no such thing as "ASCII 225". ASCII is only 7-bit. But at this point you're asking a different question - so you should ask it in a new post. Asking additional questions is *not* what comments are for.

Comment: System not allowing me to ask more question. I got the theory of `OutputStream/InputStream` and `Writer/Reader` now I want to practically test it. as I ask new question in comment about why it allowing more than one byte at a time. But unable to ask as separate new question

Comment: @LetDoit: Well trying to skirt around the restriction by asking questions in the wrong place isn't valid approach. Follow the instructions in the page which is prohibiting you from asking any more questions now.

Comment: System saying to wait for about 1 day to ask more question. Can you explain any where else that I asked?

Comment: @LetDoit: If you're being asked to wait a day to ask a question, then do that. You won't be doing yourself any favours trying to get round the restrictions by putting questions in comments.

Comment: Thanks, I used FileOutputStream to write text, and it's slow. Now I have to use the FileWriter.

Comment: @Jarkid: No, using FileWriter is a really bad idea, because you can't control the encoding. You may well find that using a BufferedWriter around the OutputStreamWriter fixes your performance issue.

Answer (score 5):

`FileOutputStream` is to write primitive types of data, like `int`, while `FileWriter` is to write character-oriented data.

`FileOutputStream` does not come with methods to deal with strings. If you want to use `FileOutputStream` to write a string to a file, you have to go like:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream();
String str="Hello";
byte b[]=str.getBytes();
fos.write(b);
fos.close();
```

In `Filewriter` there is no conversion between string and byte array. You could simply use:

```
FileWriter fr=new FileWriter("C:\\");
fr.write("Hello");
fr.close();
```

Do not forget to throw any exceptions if needed.

Answer (score 2):

A `FileOutputStream` writes bytes directly. A `FileWriter` encapsulates a `FileOutputStream` (by creating it in the `FileWriter` constructor as in your question) and provides convenience methods to write characters and Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question is when do use Reader/Writer and when Stream?

How to Decide Which to use:

```
1.If you are dealing with binary data (e.g. an image) use Streams.
2.If you are using non-ASCII Unicode characters, use Readers/Writers.
3.If you are using ordinary ASCII text you can (usually) use either.
```